# Run .NET exe in linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux

Is there any way to run the .NET exe (of a winform app) in Linux **without building the code in linux?** In fact I don't have the code for some of the utilities I developed earlier and would like to run them in linux.

Related to : [Feasibility of C# development with Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797093/feasibility-of-c-development-with-mono)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Mono ! http://mono-project.com/Main_Page

Works great too. There's a growing tool support, C# compiler etc
in a growing community.

Comment: I need to run a .NET exe file. I know that .NET programs can be built using mono. But can we run .NET exe (created in windows)  in linux?

Comment: mono is an implementation of the CLR. assemblies built against the .net framework on windows can be run on mono without recompiling

Comment: yes, we build in visual studio and deploy on linux and run under mono

Answer (score 4):

You can test it by using the Mono Migration Analyzer or by actually testing it using the Mono command prompt...covered in this [article](http://mono-project.com/Guide:_Porting_Winforms_Applications)

Answer (score 2):

Wine + .NET

Comment: Incorrect answer. .NET applications (IL code) generally cannot be run using wine!

Comment: I do believe, that .NET (>=2.0 iirc) can be installed in wine.

Comment: Check http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2586 for the status of running .NET in Wine. It seems 2.0 is Bronze (which means your assembly may or may not run depending on the libs it uses).