# Making existing C# Windows Application run on linux

Tags: c#, windows, linux, mono

Duplicate: [Run .NET exe in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800999/run-net-exe-in-linux)

Hello,

Is it possible to make my existing Windows Forms Application made using Visual Studio 2008 and .Net framework 2.0 run on Linux by recompiling in Linux with less/No code changes?

Thanks

Comment: Not an "exact duplicate" - but only because of the mistaken assumption that recompilation is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

very possible, however, depending on your application your mileage may vary. no-nos include third party libraries/DLLs that depend on COM and Win32 calls, and P/Invokes. you may also have to watch out for code that does file/directory concatenation, as unix uses "/" as directory separator while Windows uses "\".

Comment: Moreover on the directory separator, a backslash *is* a valid character in a file name on Linux, whereas windows converts forwards slashes to back slashes. Also, in windows, my understanding is that file names are case-insensitive

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you recompile the same code in the Mono IDE, and by making any minor alterations that may be required. I've done this many times.

Answer (score 0):

You may pick up some info here: [Run .NET exe in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800999/run-net-exe-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can, last I checked, their DataGridView is improving, it can hide columns now, however their VirtualMode on dgv isn't working yet.

I use Mono mostly for Remoting stuff, the DateTime type are now Remoting-compatible(yipee!) in Mono 2.4.  before (in 1.9), I have to cast my datetime fields to string so it can be transported from and to Remoting middle-tier, this is not needed anymore in 2.4.

Use this guideline for writing portable software: http://mono-project.com/Guidelines:Application_Portability

an example:

> To write portable software, you must
>   make sure that you use the
>   System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
>   (http:/monodoc/P:System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)
>   character when you must concatenate
>   paths, or even better, use the
>   System.IO.Path.Combine
>   (http:/monodoc/M:System.IO.Path.Combine(string,string))
>   method to combine pathnames.