# Will c# application run on linux OS

Tags: c#, .net, linux

I`m developing an application which receives data from my GPS device like coordinates, speed etc via GPRS of the device to my linux OS server using IP and PORT no.

I want to know does .NET framework 4.0 applications will run on linux OS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run .NET exe in linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800999/run-net-exe-in-linux)

Comment: You mean to reinstall VS2010 and .NET framework in Linux OS

Comment: you cant run C# application on Linux OS. However few windows application can be installed on Linux using Wine but C# application using serial port to access external device cant run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mono to run C# applications on linux.  I believe 3.5 is the latest framework that is supported however.  You can check it out here: [Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)

Comment: If I use a pirated copy of windows server will I able to run .NET application with out the use of this mono?

Comment: @venkateshyeluri you are not suppose to install pirated version of windows server :)

Comment: Alright I will purchase a licensed version. Will I require to install mono and recompile my programs using mono in my windows server?

Comment: No, as long as you install .Net on your server, your programs will run fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add (on top of the possible duplicate and related to 4.0)...
http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility

```
The easiest way to describe what Mono currently supports is: 
Everything in .NET 4.0 except WPF, EntityFramework and WF, limited WCF.
```